# path syntax for traversing python objects

Tags: python, xpath, jsonpath

Is there an expression-based tool for querying python complex objects the same way one can do using XPath for XML or jsonpath for JSON?

I thought about serializing my object to JSON and then using jsonpath on it, but it seems to be a clumsy way of doing that.

Comment: What do you mean by "complex objects"? Nested dictionaries?

Comment: I mean something as complex as a JSON object: a traversable tree of elements that can be bool, str, int, float, and also dict (as for an object) and list (as for an array). But the root element would be a dictionary, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in library `json` to import json as a nested dictionary and traverse it using dictionary notation - `root['level1_object']['level2_object']`. JSON-compatible object types are of course loaded as corresponding Python types.

For other types of data there are other libraries, which mostly behave in similar fashion.

My new favourite is [Box](https://pypi.org/project/python-box/), which allows you to traverse nested dictionaries using a dot notation.

Comment: Box seems promising, I'll take a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at AST module:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

Comment: How would you query 'complex objects' using AST ?

Comment: I might have misunderstood it, but it seems I would need to have my root dictionary serialized to string in order to use that. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

@vBobCat I'm currently on the search for a similar solution. Agreed that serializing and deserializing with json is not ideal. What did you end up going with?

I found http://objectpath.org/ to be close to the right solution for my use case though it lacks features in making arbitrary updates to fields that I need. Its syntax, though slightly different than JSONPath, expresses many of the things that JSONPath does.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer. My use case was simple enough so I used the `Box` library (in accepted answer) combined with `exec()`, so I can interpolate stored paths in a string and execute it.

Comment: Hello again, I don't know wether it remains useful for you after all this time, actually [jsonpath-rw](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-rw/) seems to be the library we were looking for.

Comment: Hey @VBobCat, oops I didn't think to update this, but yes I arrived at the same conclusion as you. I assumed initially that the library required a json string as input, but that turned out to be incorrect and that you can pass it dictionaries and lists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer for the sake of future researchers:

It seems **[jsonpath-rw](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-rw/)** is the library I was looking for since the beginning, since it does exactly what I originally requested.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a non-library option here. A method that finds a nested element based on a dot notation string (can traverse nested `dicts` and `lists`), see below of [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/davidverweij/cc65872bb1f3ef6d6009dd56fcd060a9):

```py
from functools import reduce
import re
from typing import Any, Optional

def find_key(dot_notation_path: str, payload: dict) -> Any:
    """Try to get a deep value from a dict based on a dot-notation"""

    def get_despite_none(payload: Optional[dict], key: str) -> Any:
        """Try to get value from dict, even if dict is None"""
        if not payload or not isinstance(payload, (dict, list)):
            return None
        # can also access lists if needed, e.g., if key is '[1]'
        if (num_key := re.match(r"^\[(\d+)\]$", key)) is not None:
            try:
                return payload[int(num_key.group(1))]
            except IndexError:
                return None
        else:
            return payload.get(key, None)

    found = reduce(get_despite_none, dot_notation_path.split("."), payload)
   
    # compare to None, as the key could exist and be empty
    if found is None:
        raise KeyError()
    return found

# Test cases:

payload = {
    "haystack1": {
        "haystack2": {
            "haystack3": None, 
            "haystack4": "needle"
        }
    },
    "haystack5": [
        {"haystack6": None}, 
        {"haystack7": "needle"}
    ],
    "haystack8": {},
}

find_key("haystack1.haystack2.haystack4", payload)
# "needle"
find_key("haystack5.[1].haystack7", payload)
# "needle"
find_key("[0].haystack5.[1].haystack7", [payload, None])
# "needle"
find_key("haystack8", payload)
# {}
find_key("haystack1.haystack2.haystack4.haystack99", payload)
# KeyError
```